# React, Webpack and Babel for Internet Explorer 9

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-9, webpack, babeljs

Trying to support IE 9 for React. Upgraded to use `babel 6.3.26` and `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-preset-react` for Webpack. However, when the file is loaded in IE 9, a syntax error occurs.

webpack.config.js

```
/* eslint-env node */
var path = require('path');
var packageJson = require('./package.json');
var _ = require('lodash');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var context = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var configFunctions = {
    development: getDevConfig,
    production: getProdConfig,
    test: getTestConfig
};

var config = configFunctions[context]();

console.log('Building version %s in %s mode', packageJson.version, context);

module.exports = config;

function getLoaders() {
    if (context.indexOf('test') === -1) {
        return [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(test|node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime']
                }
            }
        ]
    } else {
        return [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

function getBaseConfig() {
    return {
        context: __dirname + "/src",
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            publicPath: '/static/'
        },
        stats: {
            colors: true,
            reasons: true
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        },
        module: {
            loaders: _.union(
                getLoaders(),
                [
                    {
                        test: /\.scss$/,
                        loader: 'style!css!sass'
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.eot$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$/,
                        loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=fonts/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(png|.jpe?g|gif)$/,
                        loader: 'url-loader?limit=5000&name=img/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.mp4$/,
                        loader: 'url-loader?limit=5000&name=videos/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
                    }
                ]
            )
        }
    };

}

function getDevConfig() {
    return _.merge({}, getBaseConfig(), {
        devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
        entry: [
            'babel-polyfill',
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
            './App'
        ],
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
        ],
        eslint: {
            emitError: false,
            failOnError: false,
            failOnWarning: false,
            quiet: true
        }
    });
}

function getProdConfig() {
    return _.merge({}, getBaseConfig(), {
        devtool: 'source-map',
        entry: [
            'babel-polyfill',
            './App'
        ],
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                minimize: true,
                compress: {
                    warnings: false
                }
            })
        ],
        eslint: {
            emitError: true,
            failOnError: true
        }
    })
}

function getTestConfig() {
    return _.merge({}, getBaseConfig(), {})
}
```

Checking `bundle.js` for the offending lines reveals the usage of `const` which is not ES5. Am I missing something here? Do I need to transpile ES6 code into ES5 for production usage?

Answer (score 3):

IE9 is not compatible with ES6, so, yes, you must transform your ES6 code to ES5. I believe the problem is you aren't telling babel to use the `react` and `es2015` presets. I'm sure you installed them on your machine, but the babel loader only does what you tell it.

Inside your `getLoaders()` function, add the presets to your babel loader configuration query:

```
query: {
  plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
  presets: ['react', 'es2015']
}
```

Hopefully, that works for you.

[babel/babel-loader reference](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)

Comment: Sorry, left out the presets as they are in `.babelrc`, have edited my question.

Comment: @mrkre Oh okay. However, in your edit, the presets are still in the wrong place. They should be in the `query` definition along with your `plugins`. I'm not sure what else could be causing the issue for you. Sorry.

Comment: You're right, though probably not the cause of the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As of Babel v6, all the yearly presets have been deprecated. We recommend using @babel/preset-env instead. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2015/

Answer (score 0):

I am using create-react-app (v16.4.2). I tried using the followings to get the default hello world working in IE9:

1:

```
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

2:

```
import "babel-polyfill";

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But neither of them worked for me. I ended up adding the following line into my index.html file in the public folder and it fixed my issue:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

More information is available at:https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/